# PHP radiobutton testing

Tags: php, radio-button

I am creating a search facility for my website in PHP. Essentially I have two radiobuttons, one labeled "users" and the other labeled "topics", the idea being that the user will have the ability to search either users or topics in my website.

Here is the code for the search form:

```
<form name = "search" action = "search_result.php" method = "get" style = "float:right;">
<input type = "text" name = "query" id = "query" maxlength = "100">
<br />
<p><label for = "user">Search users
      <input type = "radio" name = "options" id = "user" value = "user">
  </label>
 <label for = "topics">&nbsp;Search topics
    <input type = "radio" name = "options" id = "topics" value = "topics">
 </label></p>
<input type = "Submit" value = "Go">
</form>
```

I have tried this approach:

```
if($_GET['user']==checked)//Base on specific radiobutton and check if checked
```

I have also tried this one:

```
if($_GET['options']=="users")//Base on grouped radiobuttons
```

But neither has worked. How can I check which button has been checked with PHP? When answering, please bear in mind that I have no experience with jQuery.

Comment: Your second approach seems to be correct. Try debuggin your script using `print_r($_GET);`

Comment: Use `print_r` or `var_dump` whenever you are not sure how exactly data you are receiving is structured. So output the contents of $_GET in your case, and see what values you are actually getting. Basically: Do debugging instead of guessing.

Comment: why not by `if (isset($_GET['options']))`?

Comment: It's 'user' not 'users'! On your second approach.

Comment: @CBroe Here is the output from `print_r($_GET)`: [query] => hello [options] => topics

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You checking as

```
if($_GET['options']=="users")
```

While value seems to be `user` so just change it to

```
if($_GET['options']=="user")
```

Or other way change value of your field to `users`.

Comment: you are all right! I feel stupid. sorry :)

Comment: Happens with all :) Happy Coding !!

Answer (score 1):

Remember that checkboxes and radiobuttons will send nothing on submit if not checked. 
Once checked, they will send a value, if specified, or simply `on`. So, you need to check this way:

```
if($_GET['options']== "user")
```

to check if user radiobutton checked or

```
if($_GET['options']== "topics")
```

to check if topics checked.

And remember that only name is passed on submit and it will be used as a key in `$_GET`, `$_POST` or `$_REQUEST`

Answer (score 1):

this shd work

```
if($_GET['options']=="user")


not


users
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this condition, it will surely work for you

```
if($_GET['options']=='user'){

}
```

Comment: +1 for stating what everyone else said. I am so stupid that I need to compensate everyone with rep for asking this question.